# Mongodb upsert command in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have created a collection named Account.

At first shot, I am inserting around 5 records.

```
{"Id":"0012800000C6Q19AAF","Name":"Aditya Kumar"}
{"Id":"0012800000C6MldAAF","Name":"GenePoint"}
{"Id":"0012800000C6MlbAAF","Name":"United Oil & Gas, UK"}
{"Id":"0012800000C6MlcAAF","Name":"United Oil & Gas, Singapore"}
{"Id":"0012800000C6MlTAAV","Name":"Edge Communications"}
{"Id":"0012800000C6MlUAAV","Name":"Burlington Textiles Corp of America"}
```

I am bringing data from the external system, which has already an ID field associated with it.

Again next time when a request comes for inserting extra 5 records, I want to check if Id field of upcoming records already exists in my MongoDB(if yes, then do an update else insert).

And don't get confused by Id field coming from external system with _Id field created for every MongoDB document.

Here is what I have tried:

```
var x= fields["data"]; obj='Account';
db.createCollection(obj);

db.collection(obj).insert(fields, function(err, doc) {
  if (err) {
    handleError(res, err.message, "Failed to create new contact.");
  } else {
    res.status(201).json(doc.ops[0]);
  }
})
```

Comment: What have you tried? There are many examples of upsert operations in the core documentation and on this very site. What is it you do not understand about how to do this?

Comment: I browsed this. First, i understood that I should have a set if the already existing record (source). then upcoming records(target). But not sure where I should use a query like a thing that I only want to insert and update on the basis of my id field.

collection.update( source, target, { upsert: true }, function(err, result, upserted) {
  ...
});

Comment: Yes that as a call signature of the method, but not necessarily representative of your actual code. How are you actually using it in context? What is the error/problem? Please use the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44321183/edit) link on your question to add details rather than posting comments.

Answer (score 15):

Use the [updateOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/) method:

```
db.collection.updateOne(
    { _id: id },
    { $set: { name: 'name' } },
    { upsert: true }
);
```

If a record with the matching `id` is found then the `name` field will be updated, otherwise a new record will be created.